# Find row and column of clicked table cell in JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an onclick function that returns the row and the column of the clicked cell from a table in JavaScript without using jQuery. What I have so far will return the column, but I can't figure out how to make it return the row.

```
  **cellToAppend.addEventListener("click", clicked);**

  **function clicked() {
    alert("clicked cell at: " + (this).cellIndex + ", ");
  }**
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `parentNode` to get the row.

```
function clicked() {
    alert("clicked cell at: " + this.cellIndex + ", " + this.parentNode.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: This works in uniform tables, but NOT in tables with spanned headers (or rows) over "logical" row/col.

Comment: True, with complex tables you'll need a method tailored specifically to that structure. This is just a generic solution that works with simple, uniform tables.